# Component is not rendering even after routing | React JS | React Router v6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, mern

For now i have two components. What i want to do is that after a successful login i will redirect the user to a homepage. But when i am trying to do that its not happening . Although the routes are changing in the url but the previous component is not going and overlapping with the new component.
I have tried other ways too but no good.  Any suggestion will be of great help [image: Before signing]

[image: After signing and first component is not going]

My Code:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Avatar from "@mui/material/Avatar";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import FormControlLabel from "@mui/material/FormControlLabel";
import Checkbox from "@mui/material/Checkbox";
import { useNavigate, Route, Link, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Test from "../../test/Test";
export default function LoginForm() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  const checkLogin = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/app/loginuser",
        {
          method: "POST",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email,
            password: password,
          }),
        }
      );
      const responseData = await response.json();
      navigate('/api/v1/app/test');
      console.log(responseData.data);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Grid>
      <Paper elevation={10}>
        <Grid align="center">
          <Avatar></Avatar>
          <h2>Sign In</h2>
        </Grid>
        {/* Login Logic */}

        <form onSubmit={checkLogin}>
          <TextField
            label="Email"
            placeholder="Enter Email"
            required
            focused
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            sx={{ margin: 5 }}
          />
          <TextField
            label="Password"
            placeholder="Enter password"
            type="password"
            required
            focused
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            sx={{ margin: 5 }}
          />
          {/* <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox name="checkedB" color="primary" />}
            label="Remember me"
          /> */}
          <Button
            type="submit"
            color="primary"
            variant="contained"
            sx={{ margin: 5 }}
            onClick={() => {}}
          >
            Sign in
          </Button>
          {/* <Typography>
            <Link href="#">Forgot password ?</Link>
          </Typography>
          <Typography>
            {" "}
            Do you have an account ?<Link href="#">Sign Up</Link>
          </Typography> */}

          <Button
            color="primary"
            variant="contained"
            onClick={() => {
              navigate("/api/v1/app/test");
            }}
          >
            Test link
          </Button>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/api/v1/app/test" exact element={<Test />} />
          </Routes>
        </form>
      </Paper>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Comment: Show the code of App.js and/or where you are defining routes.

Comment: Why don't you just use history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Routes>
        <Route path="/api/v1/app/test" exact element={<Test />} />
      </Routes>
```

This code means **"Render  component if url is domain/api/v1/app/test"**

So you need to wrap your conditional rendering logic with a parent component

example

Main.js:

```
<Routes>
<Route path="api/v1/app/userHome" exact element={<LoginPage />}>
<Route path="api/v1/app/test" exact element={<Test />}>
</Routes>
```

LoginPage.js:

```
<Grid>
      <Paper elevation={10}>
        <Grid align="center">
          <Avatar></Avatar>
          <h2>Sign In</h2>
        </Grid>
        {/* Login Logic */}

        <form onSubmit={checkLogin}>
          <TextField
            label="Email"
            placeholder="Enter Email"
            required
            focused
            value={email}
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
            sx={{ margin: 5 }}
          />
          <TextField
            label="Password"
            placeholder="Enter password"
            type="password"
            required
            focused
            value={password}
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
            sx={{ margin: 5 }}
          />
          {/* <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox name="checkedB" color="primary" />}
            label="Remember me"
          /> */}
          <Button
            type="submit"
            color="primary"
            variant="contained"
            sx={{ margin: 5 }}
            onClick={() => {}}
          >
            Sign in
          </Button>
          {/* <Typography>
            <Link href="#">Forgot password ?</Link>
          </Typography>
          <Typography>
            {" "}
            Do you have an account ?<Link href="#">Sign Up</Link>
          </Typography> */}

          <Button
            color="primary"
            variant="contained"
            onClick={() => {
              navigate("/api/v1/app/test");
            }}
          >
            Test link
          </Button>
```

Comment: It helped. Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark this answer as an answer to the post if this was the thing you were looking for :)